# Simulated Input steam seems like it's getting eaten on the first input for Junit Test

Tags: java, junit, inputstream

Using the solution I found over here:
https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/133943/JUnit:+How+to+simulate+System.in+testing%3F

I tried to write a JUnit test for my main game loop on a connect4 game I wrote for class. However, while it got me past the first input, on the second input I got a "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found" error.

I've tried "1\n2\n1\n2\n1\n2\n1\n2\n1\n" and "1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r" without it changing the issue.

I've tried paring it down to "1\n2\n" and "1\n\r2\n\r", as it's failing on the second entry. If I can get passed the second entry, then obviously I can get to the third, the fourth and so on. Basically, 1 says 'this is a text game', 2 says 'two human players.' The rest of the stream is a series of moves once the game starts, and so doesn't really matter at this time since I can't reach there on the unit tests.

It gets passed this...

```
public static boolean text_or_gi() {
    System.out.println("For text based, enter 1,"
            + " for Graphical play, enter 2.");
    int players = 1;
    boolean entered_int = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        if(input.hasNextInt())
        {
            players = input.nextInt();
            try
            {
                if (players >= 1 && players < 3)
                {
                    entered_int = true;
                }

                else
                    throw new ArithmeticException("1 or 2 player only");
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException e)
            {
                Connect4TextConsole.invalid_move();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            input.nextLine();
            //tell them to enter a valid number
            Connect4TextConsole.invalid_move();
        }
    }
    while(!entered_int);
    return players == 1;
}
```

But then reaches this -

```
public boolean aiOpponent()
{
    Connect4TextConsole.one_or_two_player();
    int players = 1;
    boolean entered_int = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        if(input.hasNextInt())
        {
            players = input.nextInt();
            try
            {
                if (players >= 1 && players < 3)
                    entered_int = true;
                else
                    throw new ArithmeticException("1 or 2 player only");
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException e)
            {
                Connect4TextConsole.invalid_move();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            input.nextLine();
            //tell them to enter a valid number
            Connect4TextConsole.invalid_move();
        }
    }
    while(!entered_int);
    return players == 1;
}
```

and then fails with this error.

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

```
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at core.Connect4ComputerPlayer.aiOpponent(Connect4ComputerPlayer.java:43)
at core.Connect4.game_loop(Connect4.java:102)
at core.Connect4.main(Connect4.java:66)
at TestConnect4.testMainGameLoop(TestConnect4.java:60)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

It looks like the input steam ran out, as if I only had '1/n'

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import core.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class TestConnect4 {
    // for simulating user input
    private static final InputStream systemIn = System.in;
    private static final PrintStream systemOut = System.out;
    private ByteArrayInputStream testIn;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream testOut;
    private static String testInput1;
    private static String testInput2;
    private static String testInput3;

    //Connect4 core objects
    private  static Connect4 game;

    private void provideInput(String data) {
        testIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
        System.setIn(testIn);
    }

    private String getOutput() {
        return testOut.toString();
    }

    public static void restoreSystemInputOutput() {
        System.setIn(systemIn);
        System.setOut(systemOut);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
    {
//      It seems like the first time it reaches an input, it eats the entire stream, so I can't get this first test to work.
        testInput1 = "1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r";
        game = new Connect4();

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception
    {
        restoreSystemInputOutput();
        testInput1 = null;
        game = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMainGameLoop() {
//        It fails on Enter Number of Human Players, with a NoSuchElementException. I think
//        that the first time Scanner is called, it's eating the entire input, but that shouldn't
//        happen.
        provideInput(testInput1);
        Connect4.main(new String[0]);
        assertTrue("red won", getOutput().contains("Player X  – you win!"));
    }


}
```

edit:
I've expanded my tests over the day, including using the above method in smaller ways, and it has worked for those smaller portions, but hasn't gotten me any nearly to getting the main game-loop test to work.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import core.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestConnect4 {
    // for simulating user input
    private static final InputStream systemIn = System.in;
    private static final PrintStream systemOut = System.out;
    private ByteArrayInputStream testIn;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream testOut;
    private static String testInput1;
    private static String testInput2;
    private static String testInput3;
    private static String testInput4;

    //Connect4 core objects
    private static Connect4 game;
    private static Connect4ComputerPlayer ai;

    private void provideInput(String data) {
        testIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
        System.setIn(testIn);
    }

    public void setUpOutput() {
        testOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(testOut));
    }

    private String getOutput() {
        return testOut.toString();
    }

    public static void restoreSystemInputOutput() {
        System.setIn(systemIn);
        System.setOut(systemOut);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
    {
//      It seems like the first time it reaches an input, it eats the entire stream, so I can't get this first test to work.
        testInput1 = "1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r2\n\r1\n\r";
        testInput2 = "1\n";
        testInput3 = "2\n";
        testInput4 = "3\n2\n";
        game = new Connect4();
        ai = new Connect4ComputerPlayer();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        game = new Connect4();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception
    {
        restoreSystemInputOutput();
        testInput1 = null;
        game = null;
        ai = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMainGameLoop() {
////        It fails on Enter Number of Human Players, with a NoSuchElementException. I think
////        that the first time Scanner is called, it's eating the entire input, but that shouldn't
////        happen.
        provideInput(testInput1);
        setUpOutput();
        Connect4.main(new String[0]);
        assertTrue( getOutput().contains("human players"));
        restoreSystemInputOutput();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInilization()
    {
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(), 'p');
        game.setGamestate('T');
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(), 'T');
        assertEquals(game.getPlayer(), 'X');
        game.setPlayer('O');
        assertEquals(game.getPlayer(), 'O');
        assertEquals(game.getComputer_move(), 0);
        game.setComputer_move(1);
        assertEquals(game.getComputer_move(), 1);
        int[][] columns = new int[7][6];
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        assertEquals(game.getColumns(),columns);
        columns[0][0] = -1;
        game.setColumns(columns);
        assertEquals(game.getColumns(),columns);
        assertEquals(game.isTwoplayer(), false);
        game.setTwoplayer(true);
        assertEquals(game.isTwoplayer(), true);
        game.setInput(new Scanner(System.in));
        assertNotNull(game.getInput());
    }
    @Test
    public void testWinCondition()
    {
        int[][] columns = new int[7][6];
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 1);
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'p');
        game.setColumns(columns);
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'T');
        game.setPlayer('O');
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'O');
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, -1);
        game.setPlayer('X');
        game.setColumns(columns);
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'X');
        game.setGamestate('p');
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        columns[0][0] = columns[1][0] = columns[2][0] = columns[3][0] = -1;
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'X');
        game.setGamestate('p');
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        columns[0][0] = columns[1][1] = columns[2][2] = columns[3][3] = -1;
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'X');
        game.setGamestate('p');
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        columns[3][0] = columns[2][1] = columns[1][2] = columns[0][3] = -1;
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'X');
        game.setPlayer('O');
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        columns[0][0] = columns[1][0] = columns[2][0] = columns[3][0] = 1;
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'O');
        game.setGamestate('p');
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        columns[0][0] = columns[1][1] = columns[2][2] = columns[3][3] = 1;
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'O');
        game.setGamestate('p');
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        columns[3][0] = columns[2][1] = columns[1][2] = columns[0][3] = 1;
        game.win_condition();
        assertEquals(game.getGamestate(),'O');
    }

    @Test
    public void testPlayTurn()
    {
        int[][] columns = new int[7][6];
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 1);
        assertTrue(game.play_turn(0));
        game.setColumns(columns);
        assertFalse(game.play_turn(0));
        game.setPlayer('O');
        columns[6][5] = 0;
        assertTrue(game.play_turn(6));
    }

    @Test
    public void testaiOpponent()
    {
        provideInput(testInput2);
        assertTrue(ai.aiOpponent(new Scanner(System.in)));
        provideInput(testInput3);
        assertFalse(ai.aiOpponent(new Scanner(System.in)));
        provideInput(testInput4);
        assertFalse(ai.aiOpponent(new Scanner(System.in)));
        int[][] columns = new int[7][6];
        for (int[] row: columns)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        assertTrue(ai.make_move(columns) < 7 && ai.make_move(columns) >= 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFinalState()
    {
        setUpOutput();
        game.setGamestate('X');
        Connect4.final_state(game);
        assertTrue(getOutput().contains("X"));
        game.setGamestate('O');
        Connect4.final_state(game);
        assertTrue(getOutput().contains("O"));
        game.setGamestate('T');
        Connect4.final_state(game);
        assertTrue(getOutput().contains("The Game was Tied."));
        game.setGamestate('F');
        Connect4.final_state(game);
        assertTrue(getOutput().contains("The game has entered a failed state."));
    }
}
```

So the method definitely works. Somehow, I'm dumping the stream when I test the main game loop, but not when I try it on individual portions, but I don't see where I'm doing it.

Comment: I wondered if recreating Scanner and setting it to System.in was what was causing the problem, so I created a static Scanner,  `static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` and used it rather than creating a bunch of scanners as I moved through the program. It didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Actually, while the code works fine, switching to a static Scanner might have made the problem worse, as it now doesn't seem to notice my simulated input stream at all, and simply hangs instead of failing. So that's worse.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that my first guess, that I needed to create a single Scanner and reuse it, was right. However, the scanner could not be a static Scanner - so I created a Scanner in Main, and passed it to each method in turn as I moved through the application.

This obviously is a flawed solution, and there should be a better way of doing this, as it's not how you would write a 'real' program, but it does solve the issue for the purposes of a piece of homework like this where you're job is to get a certain percentage of coverage on your unit testing, rather than actually do good unit testing.